# Add Gradle properties to application.properties resource

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have mutli-module Gradle application and I would to add properties which I've defined in `gradle.properties` to be available in `application.properties` of all my subprojects in `/src/main/resources` folder.

What I've alread tried is adding `processResources` plugin to `subprojects` section.

```
subprojects {

    processResources {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
// ...
```

As an example, I've defined the following property in `gradle.properties` file:

```
appVersion='0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Now, I want it to be present in `application.properties`, so I've added a placeholder as stated [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html). So, my `application.properties` looks the following way:

```
app.version=${appVersion}
```

Later on, I would like to use it using `Spring`, e.g.:

```
@Value("${app.version}")
```

However, after the project is built, properties are not replaced, so I have no version value in `application.properties` and still `${appVersion}` placeholder. Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not in the `Gradle` configuration, but how my `Spring Boot` application started. I was running `main()` method directly from Intellij IDEA, which didn't work for me well, probably some of the tasks were not executed properly.

So, the solution is to run `./gradlew bootRun` command. This way properties are getting correctly replaced.

Answer (score 3):

I feel strongly that you should have separate folders for separate purposes. Therefore I suggest moving `application.properties` to `src/main/filteredResources`. Then:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/main/filteredResources'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: project.properties)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, maybe I will separate resources as you advised. However, the problem was in the way I was running my application, I've already answered my own question.

Comment: Using `expand()` on the whole `FileCollection` is a bad idea. It will be slow and may also corrupt binaries (eg images)

Comment: Thanks, I will change that to be only for application.properties file.